# Throw an error from the trigger?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

When trigger returns NULL, row is not inserted, but result of the operation is still reported as successful (`INSERT 0 0`). And in my opinion this is not logical, as one would probably want to handle this properly. I wonder if there's a way to throw an actual error from the trigger?

Comment: Please add the actual trigger to show us what are you trying to achieve. And tag your PostgreSQL version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the trigger function is written in PL/pgSQL, then you can raise errors with [RAISE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE):

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_trigger() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF random() < 0.01 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'internal error';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```